# SQL Solution for deleting duplicates till 0 rows deleted

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, sqlplus

actually im looking for a sql statement, which delete my duplicate records till 0 rows deleted.

Already the sql-statement below delete duplicate records but i have to execute it several times till 0 rows deleted.

```
delete from results_table where rowid in
            (select min(rowID)  from results_table
            group by u_name||u_date
            having count(*) > 1 )
```

My conclusion is to run it only one time till 0 rows deleted.

Many thanks in advance for suggestions . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about deleting all at once?

```
delete from results_table
where rowid not in (select min(rowID)
                    from results_table
                    group by u_name, u_date
                   );
```

Or, because you seem to want the *maximum* row id:

```
delete from results_table
where rowid not in (select max(rowID)
                    from results_table
                    group by u_name, u_date
                   );
```